# Libuv UDP basic send

Tags: c, libuv

When I try to send some basic UDP message it looks like it doesn't send it.
I tried to run couple of examples that I found online.
I am using SocketTest v3.0.0 for testing server/client.
When I tested TCP sending everything worked as expected, but I UDP case it simply doesn't.

Can you provide some really basic UDP send code snippet ?
For example the receiver will be on localhost and the message will contain "test" and it will be fixed length ?

And I have one more small question. It I send the message on local host can the application(server) itself receive it and think that someone else has send it (causing looping) because it does not connect to some peer it just send the message and listen on same ip-port ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you elaborate what is not working? What code did you try? [This test](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/test/test-udp-send-and-recv.c) should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, I tried couple of examples. On sending it returns '0', so it supposed to be sent, but no message is received. I will try those tests.
The firewall shouldn't block the messages, right?

Comment: uv_udp_send returning 0 doesn't men the message will be received, what does the on_recv callback's status say?  Many corporate firewalls may block UDP traffic, have you tried localhost just to be sure?

Comment: The test that you mentioned seem to work. I tried so many others ... :X. I will give some example to close the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of usefull examples here: https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/networking.html

```
uv_loop_t *loop;
uv_udp_t send_socket;
uv_udp_t recv_socket;

int main() {
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    uv_udp_init(loop, &recv_socket);
    struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 68, &recv_addr);
    uv_udp_bind(&recv_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, UV_UDP_REUSEADDR);
    uv_udp_recv_start(&recv_socket, alloc_buffer, on_read);

    uv_udp_init(loop, &send_socket);
    struct sockaddr_in broadcast_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 0, &broadcast_addr);
    uv_udp_bind(&send_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&broadcast_addr, 0);
    uv_udp_set_broadcast(&send_socket, 1);

    uv_udp_send_t send_req;
    uv_buf_t discover_msg = make_discover_msg();

    struct sockaddr_in send_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("255.255.255.255", 67, &send_addr);
    uv_udp_send(&send_req, &send_socket, &discover_msg, 1, (const struct sockaddr *)&send_addr, on_send);

    return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example that shows sending UDP packets and receiving the response from the other side:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <uv.h>

uv_udp_t udp_socket;

void alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t *handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t *buf) {
  buf->base = malloc(suggested_size);
  buf->len = suggested_size;
}

void on_read(uv_udp_t *socket, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t *buf, const struct sockaddr *addr, unsigned flags){

  if (nread < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "read error %s\n", uv_err_name(nread));
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*) socket, NULL);
  } else if (nread > 0) {
    char sender[17] = { 0 };
    uv_ip4_name((const struct sockaddr_in*) addr, sender, 16);
    printf("recv from %s:%.*s\n", sender, (int)buf->len, buf->base);
  }

  if (buf && buf->base) {
    /* releases the buffer allocated on alloc_buffer() */
    free(buf->base);
  }
}

void on_send(uv_udp_send_t *req, int status) {
  if (status) {
    fprintf(stderr, "send error %s\n", uv_strerror(status));
  }
  /* releases the request allocated on send_msg() */
  if (req) free(req);
}

void send_msg(char *msg){
  uv_buf_t buf = uv_buf_init(msg, strlen(msg)+1);

  struct sockaddr_in send_addr;
  uv_ip4_addr("123.45.67.89", 2222, &send_addr);

  uv_udp_send_t *send_req = malloc(sizeof(uv_udp_send_t));
  uv_udp_send(send_req, &udp_socket, &buf, 1, (const struct sockaddr *)&send_addr, on_send);
}

int main() {
  uv_loop_t *loop = uv_default_loop();

  uv_udp_init(loop, &udp_socket);
  struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
  uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 2345, &recv_addr);
  uv_udp_bind(&udp_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, UV_UDP_REUSEADDR);
  uv_udp_recv_start(&udp_socket, alloc_buffer, on_read);

  send_msg("hi there!");
  send_msg("hello world");

  return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [stream route handler](https://github.com/Taymindis/stream_route_handler), although is new, but it's reliable and had tested with heavy traffic data transaction.

Example

```
void read_data(srh_request_t *req);
void read_data(srh_request_t *req) {
  char *a = "CAUSE ERROR FREE INVALID";

  if (strncmp( (char*)req->in_buff->start, "ERROR", 5) == 0) {
    free(a);
  }
  // printf("%d,  %.*s\n", i++, (int) (req->in_buff->end - req->in_buff->start), req->in_buff->start);
  srh_write_output_buffer_l(req, req->in_buff->start, (req->in_buff->end - req->in_buff->start));
  // printf("%d,  %.*s\n", i++, (int) (req->out_buff->end - req->out_buff->start), req->out_buff->start);
}

int main(void) {

  srh_instance_t * instance = srh_create_routing_instance(24, NULL, NULL);
  srh_add_udp_fd(instance, 12345, read_data, 1024, NULL);
  srh_add_tcp_fd(instance, 3232, read_data, 64, NULL);

  srh_start(instance, 1);

  return 0;
}
```